Не работает telebot
вот сам код:
import os 
import sys
from telebot import types
f = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'config.txt')
l = open(f'{f}' , 'r')
token = l.readline()
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'Здравствуйте, {message.from_user.first_name}')
bot.infinity_polling()

а вот ошибка которую он выдает:
2024-04-29 10:48:49,930 (__init__.py:1086 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found"
2024-04-29 10:48:49,935 (__init__.py:1088 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1081, in infinity_polling
    self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1166, in polling
    logger.info('Starting your bot with username: [@%s]', self.user.username)
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 293, in user
    self._user = self.get_me()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1353, in get_me
    apihelper.get_me(self.token)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 201, in get_me
    return _make_request(token, method_url)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 167, in _make_request   
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 194, in _check_result   
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 404. Description: Not Found   

Пытался гуглить ошибку , находил что это из одновременного обращения двух или более программ к 1 токену , ну токен менял , размещение программы в директории менял , нового бота создавал не чего не помогало

Вообщем то из за того что мой код брал токен из txt файла по средствам считывания первой строки , а для меня просто строка с токеном , то есть для меня токен в txt фале выглядел как просто строка , а для питона это строка , но в конце строки стоит знак ентера , из за этого он и не видел токен

В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
